# jQuery is returning the initial value of an element's attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

**Situation Description**

My HTML form loads with a variable number of elements that have the attribute `valid = "default"`.

As the user enters a value for each element, I use AJAX to validate the tag and set `valid` to true or false accordingly.

When the submit button is pressed, I collect the `valid` attribute values.

**Problem**

jQuery is only returning the initial values of `valid`. Is there a way to get the updated value of `valid`?

The code I'm using:

`var tags = ($('.tag').map(function () { return $(this).attr('valid') })).get();`

returns `["default", "default"]` even after the values have been updated and should be showing `["true", "false"]`

I'm new to JavaScript, jQuery and AJAX. So, if there is a better way to do this, please let me know what you think.

Comment: are you doing this inside the success ajax function? If its async, you need to get the tags after the ajax finishes

Comment: How you are setting valid?

Comment: Obviously won't work in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mL8ttwc0/) because AJAX and PHP, but you can see the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#' + field + 'cell')
```

selects `td` element , the *parent* element of `input` having `valid` attribute, not the `input` element itself, resulting in

```
.attr("valid", "false")
```

being applied to the parent `td` element , *not* the *child* `input` element.

Try removing `DOM` event attributes, changing selector to

```
        $('#' + field + 'cell')
        .attr("style", 'border:3px solid #FF0000')
        .find("[id="+field+"]").attr("valid", "false")
```

---

```
$(function() {
  function validate(field, query) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/echo/json/",
        data: {json:JSON.stringify(query)}          
    })
    .done(function(response) {
       console.log(field, response === "false", response === "true")

        //response = response.replace(/[[\]]/g,'');
        if(response === 'false') {
            $('#' + field + 'cell')
            .attr("style", 'border:3px solid #FF0000')
            .find("[id="+field+"]").attr("valid", "false")
        }
        else {
            $('#' + field + 'cell')
            .attr("style", 'border: none')
            .find("[id=" + field + "]")
            .attr("valid", "true")

        }
    })
    .fail(function() {
        $('#response').html('error');
    })
    .always(checkForm) // added to verify `checkForm` at each `$.ajax` call
  }

  function checkForm(variable) {
    var tags = $.map($(".tag"), function (el) { return $(el).attr('valid') });

    console.log(tags);
  }

  $("#submitButton").on("click", function(e) {
     checkForm()
  });

  $("[id^=tag]").on("blur", function(e) {
      validate(e.target.id, e.target.value)
  });
});
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/mL8ttwc0/2/